# "Prelude.read: no parse", own data type

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

I'm trying to read from file two lists of own data type 'BoardEdge'. When I try to run code I get exception:

> "Main.hs: Prelude.read: no parse"

As I suspect I get this on function responsible for validatation of input (validateInput). When I try this function in ghci inserting two BoardEdge 'objects' it works well and gives True.

Can anyone provide me with advice what am I doing wrong and how can I solve the problem?

Data types:

```
data Field = Empty | Black | Yellow deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show, Read)

data BoardEdge = BoardEdge { colRow :: [[(Field, Int)]]} deriving (Read, Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Main.hs

```
    main :: IO()
    main = do
      args <- getArgs
      input <- loadInput args
      putStrLn "Puzzle input loaded:"
      putStrLn input
      let parsedInput = parseInput input
      if (validateInput parsedInput)
        then putStrLn "Input is valid."
        else error "Input invalid!"

    -- asks for path and reads input file
    loadInput :: [String] -> IO String
    loadInput [] =  getPath >>= readFile where
      getPath = do
        putStrLn "Provide path to puzzle input file:"
        getLine
    loadDefinition (a:_) = readFile a


    -- get valid data from input file
    parseInput :: String -> (B.BoardEdge,B.BoardEdge)
    parseInput d = parseInput' $ lines d where
      parseInput' (columns: rows :_) =
        (read columns, read rows)
```

Valdiation function in Board.hs imported qualified as B:

```
    validateInput :: (B.BoardEdge,B.BoardEdge) -> Bool
    validateInput (columns, rows) = rowColEq where
      rowColEq = countBlocks columns == countBlocks rows


    -- function that counts total quantity of colored blocks
    countBlocks :: (B.BoardEdge)-> Int
    countBlocks (B.BoardEdge colRow) = countBlocks' $ concat colRow where
      countBlocks' [] = 0
      countBlocks' (x:xs) = snd x + countBlocks' xs
```

And my input files are like this:

```
    [[(Black,2),(Yellow,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Yellow,1),(Black,3)]]
    [[(Black,5)],[(Black,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Black,2)],[(Black,1),(Black,2)]]
```

Comment: Well... what's in your puzzle input file?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about this! In my input files I have two long lists that covers Board edge data type: [[(Field, Int)]]. 

it goes something like:
[[[(Black,2),(Yellow,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Yellow,1),(Black,3)]]
[[[(Black,2),(Yellow,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Yellow,1),(Black,3)]]

Comment: Here's a hint: open GHCi and try to `show` some of your data structure. What you see is the format that the automatically derived `read` will expect.

Comment: So I tried to do it now, for 'show Field' it says "data constructor not in scope: Field :: ()" and for 'show B.BoardEdge' it says that "No instance for (Show ([[(B.Field, Int)]] -> B.BoardEdge))". Making an Instance could solve my problem?

Comment: @ŁukaszNiewiński You can only `show` a "complete" value of your data type. A `BoardEdge` needs a `colRow` for instance.

Comment: @Cubic thank you for your response. So I did something like "let edge1 = BoardEdge [[(Black,2),(Yellow,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Yellow,1),(Black,3)]]" and than I did "show edge1". Is it what you had in your mind? If not I'm sorry, Im quite new to Haskell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gluing together your own code snippets and Fyodor's comment:

```
Prelude> data Field = Empty | Black | Yellow deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show, Read)
Prelude> data BoardEdge = BoardEdge { colRow :: [[(Field, Int)]]} deriving (Read, Eq, Ord, Show)
Prelude> let edge1 = BoardEdge [[(Black,2),(Yellow,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Yellow,1),(Black,3)]]
Prelude> show edge1
"BoardEdge {colRow = [[(Black,2),(Yellow,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Yellow,1),(Black,3)]]}"
Prelude> let correctInput = it -- ^^ the above
```

So now we know what `read` expects, which is what `show` produced.  How does this compare with what you used as the input?

```
Prelude> let myInput =     "[[(Black,2),(Yellow,2),(Black,1)],[(Black,2),(Yellow,1),(Black,3)]]"
Prelude> correctInput == myInput
False
```

Or less snarky: If you want default `read` instances to parse your input then your input must be correct Haskell code with data constructors and all.  In this case using `BoardEdge` was needed.

Comment: Man, thank you so much!! You exactly showed me what I was missing. I didn't think of using "BoardEdge {colRow = [.....]}". Your comparison was brilliant, thank you! :)